# What do we mean by SQL NOW() and created_at in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have been told to test someone's code and when I pass a json, it throws the following error

> Error: No Rows found
> `select * from otp_log where verified_at is NULL and (NOW()-created_at)<? and email_otp = ?  and mobile_otp = ? 300,5581`
>
> Error: No rows found

I get this error when i send a put request from postman

```
{
    
    "signup_request_id": "36", 
    "email_otp": "5881"
}
```

Now I checked that we have otp_log table in our sql and it contains email_otp and mobile_otp field already populated with data.

The route i am using is `signup/verify` which as the name suggests is used to verify a user by otp.

So can someone help me with explaining what does this exactly do. like why am I getting the error (in general)? and what does this mean `(NOW()-created_at`?

Answer (score 1):

This is a bit long for a comment.

This is a strange way to write the condition.  I think it is easier to follow as:

```
select *
from otp_log
where verified_at is NULL and 
      created_at > now() - ? and
      email_otp = ? and
      mobile_otp = ?
```

I don't know what `300,4906,20102` is supposed to be.  If it is present in the query, then it would cause a syntax error.  Otherwise, the "No rows found" means just what it says:  no rows match the `where` conditions.

Comment: Shall we need to change `created_at > now() - ?` to  `created_at > (now() - ?)`  ?

Comment: Updated my question.

Answer (score 0):

`Now()` is a sql function which returns current date time and i think  "created_at" is a column name which is available on a particular table ( in this case table name is "otp_log" so created_at is a column of this table ) where you query

so i think overall query will be

```
     select * from otp_log 
    where verified_at is NULL 
  and created_at> NOW()-? and email_otp = ?  and mobile_otp in(300,4906,20102)
```

Comment: Updated my question